# Insert Into with a select clause

Tags: select, join, insert

first time here though I have been using the site a lot, you have a very vast knowledge!

I'm trying to Insert some values in a table XXX, buy my 'where' condition is a specific value in another table YYY. I believe I need to use a 'join' sentence, but I don't know how, or where to include it.

My sentence is

---

*INSERT INTO XXX (value1, value2, value3) VALUES ('value1', 'value2', 'value3')
WHERE YYY.value = 2*;

---

but of course, it lacks of this 'join' sentence that I don't know how to use

Any suggestions? I'm trying to do this in a PostgreSQL and SQL Server Database, so any syntax would be good for me

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pretending for a moment that your sample query actually does what you want it to do, how many rows should it insert into XXX? Are you expecting it to insert a new row for each row in YYY where value = 2? That is to say, if there are 3 rows in YYY, are you wanting 3 new rows to be inserted into XXX?

Comment: Err, slight amendment to my previous comment:
That is to say, if there are 3 rows in YYY where value=2, are you wanting 3 new rows to be inserted into XXX?

Comment: mmm let me put it like this: My 'insert' clause will be inserting lets say 'people' and may or may not insert several rows on table XXX, but I know beforehand that I dont want to insert rows where 'age' = 2. The thing is, value 'age' is on a different table. Hope it's clearer now

Comment: So are the values you are trying to insert into table XXX coming from table YYY?

Comment: No, they're some values that users can freely select. I'd like to point out that I'm not quite sure if what we want to do is even possible or if it exists at all. What I mean is, I have never used a 'where' clause in an 'insert into' sentence, I don't know if that is possible

Comment: In the context of an insert statement, a where clause doesn't make sense and is not correct syntax. I can't even imagine what a where clause in that context would do, and as a result I can't guess what you are trying to do. The questions I'm asking are an attempt to determine what you would like such a construct to do, so myself or another would be able to explain how to do it. It may help if you could edit the question and lay out an example scenario of what table XXX would look like before the query, what table YYY looks like, and what table XXX would look like after the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which database do you use?

For ms-access you can use `select value1, value2, value3 from yyyy WHERE value4 = 2 into xxx`

Comment: I'm trying to do this in a PostgreSQL and SQL Server Database, so any syntax would be good for me. Anyway, I beleive that what I need is the other way round, I mean, I need to insert al my values in a table where the condition is a value on another table

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO XXX (col1,col2,col3) VALUES ('value1','value2','value3') 
WHERE XXX.id = YYY.id
AND YYY.age <> 2
```

XXX and YYY need to connect somehow (you mentioned people, could be like #SSN on a 1-1 match, or some other identifier)

Where are your values that are being inserted coming from? Even if they are user inputted, there still has to be an identifier that will link the new info with the table that has the age.

Comment: Actually, it has been some time since I had this problem, so I really cannot remember so much about it. However, I find your answer very interesting, as I haven't thought of this possibility you are presenting. Thanks!